Gnosis Safe UI + WalletConnect incompatible with ZKsync Native AA paymaster transaction type : 113
Gnosis safe UI recognizes ZKsync Paymaster Type Transaction : txType-113(https://docs.zksync.io/zksync-protocol/rollup/transaction-lifecycle#eip-712-0x71) as normal signature rather than paymaster transaction.
So, for any application that preliminary supports paymaster, Gnosis safe users that are connected with WalletConnect are not able to send paymaster transaction. Users get signature signing request on the UI but it is not the expected one by the Dapps which is deemed incorrect. Thus causing the Dapps to revert, making Gnosis safe unusable with paymaster transactions.
In this scenario, either all Dapps need to differentiate Gnosis walletConnect and disable paymaster type transactions for Gnosis wallet type connection or Gnosis safe UI handles this type transaction type : 113 is a different manner for elastic chains(For eg: using customSignature parameter as per this tutorial : https://code.zksync.io/tutorials/native-aa-multisig or something better).
While on the paymaster topic as well, every execute transaction can be converted to paymaster type transaction on Gnosis safe for ZKsync and other elastic chains, allowing signers with no funds to execute the transaction and not wait for signer with funds or connect with different wallet; without any relayers, bundlers support required thanks to Native AA's support.

Thank you for reporting this. This indeed seems to be a bug, and it has been reported to the corresponding team internally. Let me come back to you shortly to provide updates about this issue. Please hang tight in the meantime  Thank you in advance; Best, Louis
